# Calling WCF service POST method from jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have a following WCF method

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
public string HelloWorld(string stest)
{
    return stest.ToString();
}
```

And I have a jQuery Ajax client code as below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '../../Service.svc/HelloWorld',
       data: { 'stest': 'testdata' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {

        },
        error: function (error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

When ajax invoke HellowWorld method, get

> error NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error.

How I call wcf Post method from jquery ajax.

Comment: put a break point and check whether its hitting server code or not... And install fiddler to check what exatly this ajax call is sending. Here is the path for installing fiddler  http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4

Comment: Add this to your web.config `<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>` 
And Add this attribute to service class `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]`

Comment: Please update what you are getting in the fiddler request.

Comment: this problem resolved. Now I am getting another error when I pass jsonstring as a param in service

Comment: so post the solution as answer and accept that.